# Como simular < o > en C, he podido simular la pipe | pero tendo duda con la entrada y salida estandar

Tags: c, linux, shell, línea-de-comandos

Tengo una función que se encarga de saber la prioridad dada por "|" o por "<" ">", si detecta uno sube la prioridad y al tener prioridad mayor ejecuta los dos comandos, pero sólo funciona con la pipe, ya que si yo pongo por ejemplo:
ls -la | wc (son necesarios los espacios para strtok) la salida me la da correcta y bueno si yo intento hacer:
ls -la > 1.txt (donde el archivo ya fue creado) entra en un ciclo sin fin.
Aún no se bien como podria programar "<" o ">", cualquier idea es recibida, muchas gracias, les dejo mi código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>



#define MAX_ARGS 20
#define MAX_CHAR 1000

int extrae_argumentos_d(char *, char *, char *[], int);
int extrae_argumentos_leftPipe(char *, char *, char *[], int);
int extrae_argumentos_rightPipe(char *, char *, char *[], int);
void limpiaCad(char *[], int);
char* nameUser();
char* leerLinea(char*);
int verifyCad(char**, int, char *, char *);
void printARGS(char **,int);


int main(int argc,  char *argv[]){

    int pid,i,flag,exitt,temp=0, nargs, tuberia[2];
    char *args[temp], *comand[temp], comando[MAX_CHAR], nombre[20], dir[1024], wNext[10]=" ", wBefore[10]= " ";
    char *argsLeft[temp], *argsRight[temp];
    struct utsname unameD;
    int nargsLP, flagVC, nargsRP,priority=0;
    char comando2[MAX_CHAR];
    uname(&unameD);
    getcwd(dir,sizeof(dir));
    strcpy(nombre,nameUser());
    do{
        if(pipe(tuberia)== -1){
                    perror("\n [-] ERROR PIPE \n");
                    exit(-1);
            }
        pid_t pid=fork();
        if( pid == -1){
            perror("\n [-] ERROR FORK\n");
        }
        else if(pid==0){
            close(tuberia[1]);
            read(tuberia[0],comando, sizeof(comando));
            nargs=0;
            nargs = extrae_argumentos_d(comando, " ", args, MAX_ARGS);
            priority=verifyCad(&args[0], nargs,&wBefore[0], &wNext[0]);
            printf("\nPriority: %i\n", priority); //See priotity to check if works fine
                switch (priority)
                {
                case 0:
                    args[nargs]=(char *)0;
                    flag = execvp(args[0], args);

                    if(flag == -1){
                        printf("\n [-] There is not found that command or does not exist\n");
                    }
                    limpiaCad(&args[0],nargs);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    strcpy(comando2,comando);
                    nargsLP= extrae_argumentos_leftPipe(comando, " ", argsLeft, MAX_ARGS);
                    nargsRP= extrae_argumentos_rightPipe(comando2, " ", argsRight, MAX_ARGS);
                    int fd[2];
                    pipe(fd);
                    pid_t p1,p2;
                    p1=fork();
                    if(p1==0){
                        printf("\r");
                        argsRight[nargsRP]= (char *)0;
                        close(STDIN_FILENO);
                        dup(fd[0]);
                        close(fd[1]);
                        execvp(argsRight[0], argsRight);
                        //printf("\n-------------ARGS LEFT----------");
                        //printARGS(&argsLeft[0],nargsLP);
                        limpiaCad(&argsLeft[0],nargsRP);
                    }if(p1!=0){
                        p2=fork();
                        if(p2==0){
                            argsLeft[nargsLP]= (char *)0;
                            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
                            dup(fd[1]);
                            close(fd[0]);
                            execvp(argsLeft[0], argsLeft);
                            limpiaCad(&argsLeft[0],nargsLP);

                        }
                    }
                    close(fd[0]);
                    close(fd[1]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                    //c1
        }else{
            close(tuberia[0]);
            printf("\n%s@%s:~%s$ ", nombre,unameD.nodename, dir);
            leerLinea(&comando[0]);
            write(tuberia[1], comando, strlen(comando)+1);
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }while( strcmp(comando,"exit") != 0);
    return 0;
}

int extrae_argumentos_d(char *orig, char *delim, char *args[], int max_args){

    char *tmp;
    int num=0;
    char *str = malloc(strlen(orig)+1);
    strcpy(str, orig);
    args[0]= "./comando.out";
    tmp=strtok(str, delim);
    do{
        if (num==max_args)
        return max_args+1;
        args[num]=tmp;
        num++;
        tmp=strtok(NULL, delim);
    }while (tmp!=NULL);
    return num;
}
void limpiaCad(char *cad[], int lim){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<lim; i++){
        cad[i]="";
    }

}
char *nameUser(){
    char *login;
    struct passwd *pentry;
    //log user verify
    if((login = getlogin()) == NULL){
        perror("getlogin");
        exit(-1);
    }
    //Pass user veryfy
    if((pentry = getpwnam(login)) == NULL){
        perror("getpwnam");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return pentry->pw_name;
}
char *leerLinea(char *comando){
    int i;
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(comando);
    return comando;

}
int verifyCad(char **comand, int tam, char *wBefore, char *wNext){
    int priority=0;
    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
        if(strcmp(comand[i],"|") == 0 || (strcmp(comand[i],">") ==0)  || (strcmp(comand[i],"<") ==0)){
            priority++;
        }
    }
    return priority;
}

int extrae_argumentos_leftPipe(char *orig, char *delim, char *args[], int max_args){

    char *tmp;
    int band[3], f=1;
    int num=0;
    char *str = malloc(strlen(orig)+1);
    strcpy(str, orig);
    args[0]= "./comando.out";
    tmp=strtok(str, delim);
    do{
        if (num==max_args)
        return max_args+1;
        args[num]=tmp;
        num++;
        tmp=strtok(NULL, delim);
        band[0]=(strcmp(tmp,"|"));
        band[1]=(strcmp(tmp,"<"));
        band[2]=(strcmp(tmp,">"));
        if(band[0]==0){
            f=0;
        }
        if(band[1]==0){
            f=0;
        }
        if(band[2]==0){
            f=0;
        }
    }while (f);
    return num;
}
int extrae_argumentos_rightPipe(char *orig, char *delim, char *args[], int max_args){

    char *tmp;
    int band[3];
    char *str = malloc(strlen(orig)+1);
    int flag=0;
    strcpy(str, orig);
    int num=0;
    args[0]= "./comando.out";
    tmp=strtok(str, delim);
    do{
        band[0]=strcmp(tmp,"|");
        band[1]=strcmp(tmp,">");
        band[2]=strcmp(tmp,"<");
        if (band[0]==0){
            flag=1;
            tmp=strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        if (band[1]==0){
            flag=1;
            tmp=strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        if (band[2]==0){
            flag=1;
            tmp=strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        if (flag==1){
            args[num]=tmp;
            num++;
        }
        tmp=strtok(NULL, delim);
    }while  (tmp!=NULL);
    return num;
}
//Functions WF
void printARGS(char **arr,int size){
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("\n Value :%s", arr[i]);
    }

}
```

En si lo que trato de hacer es simular una minishell para linux, usando dup,exec,y fork.
Para probar los comandos tienen que dejar un espacio en cada cadena.

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Te referís a como redireccionar un archivo a `stdin` y `stdout` a un archivo?

Comment: En si me refiero a poder simular un comando que involucre los operadores ">, <, >>, <<" puedo simular una pipe "|" pero no tengo idea de como atacar el problema con los operadores de entrada y salida, es decir yo busco hacer que mi programe compile y se acapaz de ejecutar la instruccion:
ls -la > 1.txt para cuando haga un cat en "1.txt" me de el resultado de ls, o poder ejecutar otros commandos que involucren esos operadores.

Answer (score 0):

Para redireccionar `stdin`, `stdout` y `stderr`, que es lo que `<` y `>` hacen, podés usar la función `freopen`:

```c
char *in_file, *out_file, *err_file;

/* Abre in_file en modo lectura binario como stdin (`<`) */
freopen(in_file, "rb", stdin);

/* Abre out_file en modo adjunto binario como stdout (`>>`) */
freopen(out_file, "ab", stdout);

/* Abre out_file en modo escritura binario como stdout (`>`) */
freopen(out_file, "wb", stdout);

/* Abre out_file en modo adjunto binario como stdout (`2>>`) */
freopen(err_file, "ab", stderr);

/* Abre out_file en modo escritura binario como stdout (`2>`) */
freopen(err_file, "wb", stderr);
```

Entonces podés ejecutar el archivo con las funciones `exec`. Eso sí, el programa puede reemplazar `stdin`, `stdout` y `stderr` por sí mismo.